# Three JS - export scene as JSON and import JSON as scene

Tags: three.js

I just started working with Three js. I have an use case where I have to export the scene to JSON which will be stored in the database, later retrieved and loaded back in the screen.Please suggest some idea of how to do that.

Thank you all in advance.